# GPS Logger Trigger Circuit Integration

Tags: arduino, circuit-protection, gps, datalogger

The Arduino UNO and GPS shield logs the coordinates by the use of the trigger inputs.  The trigger takes +ve 5 to 15v on a pin.  (See Image 1)
It is designed to be used to log, each time a solenoid valve(s) operates in the circuit in image 2.

How do i safely integrate this trigger/logging circuit into the circuit in Image 2 and protect the logging circuit?  Which components do i require and at what points should i install them?

Thank you

[image: Image 1 - GPS Logger Image]

[image: Image 2 - Circuit Schematic]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply using an optocoupler such as [EL817](https://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/EL817.pdf) which will completely isolate your control circuit from the high voltage side.

You can connect an optocoupler to your existing system as shown below. And don't forget to turn on an internal pullup resistor of the Arduino digital pin which you are going to use as Input.

[image: Circuit]

You can also do the same thing with no optical isolation with an NPN transistor such as BC547.

[image]